# Can we create Approval process for User Object in Salesforce?

Tags: approval-process, user

What I want to do is If any one attempt to modify the User fields then It requires approval from Manager. If manager approve the request then field will be modified otherwise it will not be modified. But while creating the approval process in the **List** "**Manage approval process for**" there is no option for selecting User Object. So how can I create approval process for User object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. In fact Workflow rules for user was just recently added, if I recall correctly.

I see a few work-arounds.

1. Simple workflows. For basic things like notifications, you could make do with some workflow rules.
2. Do it in code. Create some kind of logic/process in code that implements an approval process using a combination of apex and visualforce
3. Visual Workflow could be used to walk users through a process and then request input from managers where needed.
4. Create a child object that goes through the approval by proxy. You won't be able to lock the user record, but it would give you the classic approval process features and configurability.

While you're at it, I do not see any ideas of this nature on IdeaExchange. Please submit this idea.

Comment: can you please explain How can I request input from managers in visual workflow ?

Comment: It would be the same ways as with workflow, such as sending emails, assigning tasks, and in Winter 15, I believe there is a "post to chatter" action that is to be added.